# Show Progress while downloading image from server into imageview

Tags: android, android-progressbar, picasso

I am ListView and would like to show progress, until image not downloaded from server into ImageView using Picasso library, still showing ic_launcher drawable while downloading image from server into ImageView, but what if i would like to show progress

```
    Picasso.with(context)
    .load(imageURL)
    .transform(transformation)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .into(viewHolder.imageView);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your xml file you have to put progressbar above image, **set visibility** of progressbar visible and in your code

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(file)
       .into(imageView, new Callback() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess() {
               progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
       });
```

when image is download you have to **setVisibility(View.GONE)** to progressbar

Answer (score 6):

In the passed Google Developer Summit Thailand, Google introduced us an Image Loader Library for Android developed by bumptech named Glide as a library that recommended by Google. It has been used in many Google open source projects till now including Google I/O 2014 official application.

It succeeded in making me interested. I spent a whole night playing with it and decided to share  my experience in this blog post. As a begining, I must say that it looks 90% similar to Picasso. To be more precise, I think it is something like a Picasso-clone.

Anyway it is quite different in details. You will learn how.

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Comment: thanks for sharing this blog post, very informative and useful, i will use Glide in my future projects, i tapped your answer as useful..

Answer (score 2):

Add ProgressBar to your XML where you put the ImageView , or do it programmatically. Then you could do:

```
 ProgressBar progressBar ; //initialize it as you dud with the imageView
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(imageURL)
            .transform(transformation)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .into(viewHolder.imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                @Override
                public void onError() {
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Wait a moment, loading image...");
        mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();

        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(mImagePath).into(mImageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Download failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! In current version (2.71828), the onError method should add a paramter Excepion: "public void onError(Exception e) {".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Target Class of Picasso

```
Target t = new Target() {
 @Override
 public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
         //hideProgress
}

@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
           //hideProgress
}

 @Override
  public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        //lshow Progress
 }
};

 Picasso.with(context)
.load(strImage)
.transform(transformation)
.placeholder(R.drawable.nothing_found)
.error(R.drawable.nothing_found)
.into(t);
```